# Android AWS S3 SDK TransferUtility Not Working in Service

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, android-service

I am trying to use the AWS Android SDK for S3 in a started service. I am a little new to both the SDK and Services. I am pretty confident that the Transfer Utility is also running a service.

```
Handler (android.os.Handler) {11629d87} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {11629d87} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
    at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:325)
    at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
    at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
    at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
    at sksDoneLater(TransferService.java:189)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService.access$200(TransferService.java:44)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService$2.handleMessage(TransferService.java:166)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Here is the code I am using to start it up:

```
    AmazonS3 amazonS3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
    mTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(amazonS3, getApplicationContext());
    TransferObserver observer = mTransferUtility.upload(
            S3_RAW_BUCKET_ARN,
            mVidFileKey,
            mVidFile);

    observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {...})
```

The line previous it says it can't get s3 client. I created the client just as shown above in application class and successfully used the same code in an activity to perform a successful transfer so it must be something obvious about services that I am ignorant of. The above code is called in a method that is called from `onStartCommand()` in the service.

Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE - Whole Class was requested and is shown here:

```
public class VideoCompressionService extends Service {;

private Bus bus;
private TransferUtility mTransferUtility;
private int mVidWidth;
private int mVidHeight;
private File mCompressedVidFile;
private File mVidFile;
private String mVidFileKey;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
private android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder mNotification;

public VideoCompressionService() {

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent != null) {
        String realPath = MediaUtils.getRealVideoPathFromURI(this.getContentResolver(), intent.getData());
        if (realPath != null) {
            this.mVidFile = new File(realPath);
            this.mVidFileKey = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_VID_FILE_KEY);
            this.mVidWidth = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_VID_WIDTH, 0);
            this.mVidHeight = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_VID_HEIGHT, 0);
            this.bus = CoPhotoApplication.getVideoCompressionBus();
            if (mVidFile != null && mVidFile.exists() && mVidFile.canRead()) {
                mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                mNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle("Compressing Video - Step 1 of 3")
                        .setContentText("Uploading video for processing...")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                if (mVidWidth == 0 || mVidHeight == 0) {
                    MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                    mmr.setDataSource(mVidFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    mVidWidth = Integer.parseInt(mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH));
                    mVidHeight = Integer.parseInt(mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT));
                    mmr.release();
                }
                uploadVidToS3();
            }
            return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
        } else {
            VideoCompressionService.this.stopSelf();
            return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
        }
    } else {
        VideoCompressionService.this.stopSelf();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private void uploadVidToS3() {
    compressionUploadStarted();
    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "*********ID HERE********", // Identity Pool ID
            Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
    );

    AmazonS3 amazonS3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
    mTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(amazonS3, getApplicationContext());
    TransferObserver observer = mTransferUtility.upload(
            S3_RAW_BUCKET_ARN,
            mVidFileKey,
            mVidFile);

    observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
            if (state == TransferState.COMPLETED) {
                compressionUploadFinished(true);
                zencodeVideo(mVidFileKey);
            } else if (state == TransferState.FAILED) {
                compressionUploadFinished(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
            int progress = Math.round(100 * ((float) bytesCurrent / bytesTotal));
            String progressPercentage = String.valueOf(progress) + "%";
            compressionUploadProgress(progress, progressPercentage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
            compressionUploadFinished(false);
        }
    });
}

private void compressionUploadStarted() {
    bus.post(new CompressionUploadStartedEvent());
    updateNotification();
}

private void compressionUploadProgress(int progress, String progressPercentage) {
    bus.post(new CompressionUploadProgressEvent(progress, progressPercentage));
    mNotification.setProgress(100, progress, false);
    updateNotification();
}

private void compressionUploadFinished(boolean successfully) {
    bus.post(new CompressionUploadFinishedEvent(successfully));
    if (successfully) {
        mNotification.setContentText("Upload complete");
    } else {
        mNotification.setContentTitle("Compression Failed");
        mNotification.setContentText("Upload failed. Please try again later.");
    }
    updateNotification();
    if (!successfully) {
        VideoCompressionService.this.stopSelf();
    }
}

private void updateNotification() {
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification.build());
}
```

Comment: Would you please provide the entire class?

Comment: Done. I edited the question.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't tried to use TransferUtility in a service. I'll double check whether it causes the issue. Will get back to you soon.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: I created this question for more general commentary on this issue and for future community reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186504/is-it-possible-to-use-aws-android-transferutility-in-service

Comment: @Yangfan Any updates?

Comment: Do you see this message "TransferService can't get s3 client, it will stop." in the log? My guess is that your service stops before TransferService starts and thus the S3 client is garbage collected before TransferService gets hold of it.

Comment: I'll have to try putting it in a service again to find out. I'll get back to you. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Hi @MichaelGarner, I have the same problem. Have you found any solution?

Comment: @VasilyKabunov I never found a solution and I have since moved off of the project that was going to use it.

Answer (score 10):

I found myself in the same issue...
Here it is what solved for me:

I noticed I had the following service for my SyncAdapter registered in Manifest:

```
        <service
        android:name=".sync.SyncService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":sync">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
    </service>
```

The android:process=":sync" tells service to run in a private process called :sync
So I just told the TransferService from Amazon SDK to run in this same thread.

```
        <service
        android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService"
        android:process=":sync"
        android:enabled="true" />
```

After that, I no more got the error **TransferService can't get s3 client, and it will stop**, and finally was able to upload my pictures to S3

Comment: This helped me since I was using the TransferUtility in a service. I found myself needing to use the TransferUtility in an Activity now too, and it's not working because I've decalred that the TransferService run on my service's thread. Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 2):

You should declare the client as a global variable, as the garbage collector could delete it if you don't do it.