# AWS S3 uploads stuck in WAITING state

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

I've looked at several questions and answers about this but I'm still unable to upload to an S3 bucket. I have alreadydeclared the service in the manifest within the application tags.

Every log statement returns the correct information, but the status is always WAITING and none of the transfer listeners are triggered. I do not receive any errors whatsoever and the S3 bucket continues to be empty.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public void uploadStoredItems() {

    TransferUtility transferUtility = TransferUtility.builder()
            .context(AWSProvider.getInstance().getContext())
            .awsConfiguration(AWSProvider.getInstance().getConfiguration())
            .s3Client(new AmazonS3Client(AWSProvider.getInstance().getIdentityManager().getCredentialsProvider()))
            .build();

    try {
        for (File csvFile : csvFiles) {
            String filename = csvFile.getName(); //.substring(csvFile.getName().lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            Log.d(TAG, "This is the filename for upload: " + filename);

            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
            String line = null;
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(csvFile);

            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Here are the lines: " + line);
            }

            // Always close files.
            bufferedReader.close();

            TransferObserver uploadObserver = transferUtility.upload(filename, csvFile);
            // Gets id of the transfer.
            Log.d(TAG, "This is the bucket: " + uploadObserver.getBucket());
            Log.d(TAG, "This is the state: " + uploadObserver.getState());
            Log.d(TAG, "This is the id: " + uploadObserver.getId());

            observers = transferUtility.getTransfersWithType(TransferType.UPLOAD);
            TransferListener listener = new TransferListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onStateChanged: " + state.toString());
                    if (TransferState.COMPLETED == state) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "COMPLETE: " + state.toString());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
                    float percentDonef = ((float) bytesCurrent / (float) bytesTotal) * 100;
                    int percentDone = (int) percentDonef;

                    Log.d(TAG, "ID:" + id + " bytesCurrent: " + bytesCurrent
                            + " bytesTotal: " + bytesTotal + " " + percentDone + "%");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                    // Handle errors
                    Log.d(TAG, "ERROR ID:" + id + " " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            };

            for (TransferObserver observer : observers) {

                if (TransferState.WAITING.equals(observer.getState())
                        || TransferState.WAITING_FOR_NETWORK.equals(observer.getState())
                        || TransferState.IN_PROGRESS.equals(observer.getState())) {
                    observer.setTransferListener(listener);
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "\n observers - id: " + observer.getId() + " state: " + observer.getState() + " key: " + observer.getKey() + " bytes total: " + observer.getBytesTotal());
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Bytes Total: " + uploadObserver.getBytesTotal());

        }
        csvFiles.clear();
    } catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file");
    } catch(java.io.IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try removing `observers = transferUtility.getTransfersWithType(TransferType.UPLOAD);` and attaching the listener to the uplaodObserver only? `uploadObserver.setTransferListener(listener)`. There appears to be a synchronization issue in the database between the upload operation and the query operation done by getTransfersWithType? Let me know how this goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I have to declare the TransferUtility service to run in the same process that the service I am calling it from is running:

```
<application

    ...

    <service
      android:name=".MainService"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:process=":main_service"
      android:stopWithTask="false" />
    <service
      android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService"
      android:process=":main_service"
      android:enabled="true" />

    ...

</application>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is this change required only when you invoke transfer utility from a service context?

Comment: It seems like it is, although I haven't read it officially anywhere. I just found an example of someone fixing an issue by doing the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44989769/5927903

Comment: I am doing it from a different class on main thread and it is stuck in WAITING. Can you help?